# ¿Cómo calcular el promedio de una matriz bidimencional?

Tags: java

tengo una duda, necesito sacar el promedio de una matriz bidimensional no se si lo estoy haciendo bien o mal, tengo el siguiente método que recibe como parámetro una matriz[12][4] que ya tengo declarada y un método llenar la matriz aleatoriamente, pero el problema es como le puedo sacar el promedio de toda la matriz.

```
int promedio = 0;  // esta variable la voy a usar en otro metodo     public int Promedio(int matriz[][]) {
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                suma += matriz[i][j];              
                promedio = suma / matriz.length;            
            }
        }
        return promedio;                           
    }
```

Comment: y probaste este metodo? anda mal? tiene algun problema? lo probaste? cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un promedio es la suma de los elementos entre el total de elementos.

```
    int suma = 0;
    int totalElementos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            // 1. sumar todos los elementos
            suma += matriz[i][j];
            // esta variable se usa para contar los elementos
            totalElementos++;
        }
    }
    // retornar la suma de elementos entre el total de elementos (promedio)
    return suma / totalElementos;
```

Usar `matriz.length` no funciona debido a que la matriz tiene dos dimensiones, por lo tanto si es de 12 x 4 tendrá 48 elementos.